# Where are the digital and analog pins for the adafruit atmega 32u4 breakout board?

Tags: arduino-leonardo

Which pins are the analog and digital pins? I've been searching the internet for an hour and I could get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information is right there on the product page for you. It took be a total of about 4 seconds to find it.

http://ladyada.net/products/atmega32u4breakout/

[image]